# MKReverseGeocoder: where is location string stored?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

I found this tutorial:

http://evilrockhopper.com/2010/01/iphone-development-reverse-geocoding/

and implemented this code:

```
if (reverseGeocoder != nil)
{
    // release the existing reverse geocoder to stop it running
    [reverseGeocoder release];
}

// use whatever lat / long values or CLLocationCoordinate2D you like here.
CLLocationCoordinate2D locationToLookup = {52.0,0};
MKReverseGeocoder *reverseGeocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:locationToLookup];
reverseGeocoder.delegate = self;
[reverseGeocoder start];
```

The question is, when I started reverseGeocoding, where is location string stored?
I have coordinate and I give them to reverseCeocoder to find me address, but how to get this address in some string for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read the documentation for `MKReverseGeocoder`:

> The reverse geocoder returns information through its associated delegate object, which is an object that conforms to the `MKReverseGeocoderDelegate` protocol.

So you have to implement these two methods in your delegate:

```
– reverseGeocoder:didFindPlacemark:
– reverseGeocoder:didFailWithError:
```

and the geocoder will call them when it has information for you.